# Can I flash another modem firmware from a CWM recovery (and not touch the main installed OS otherwise)?

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, radio-firmware

On a Samsung Galaxy S, I followed [the complete instructions for installing CyanogenMod 10](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_galaxysmtd), and now I have CM10 as the main system, and a ClockWorkMod-based recovery system (from Replicant), which is bootable by holding VolUp and VolDown when powering up the device. (BTW, CM10 allows to choose to reboot into recovery through the usual PowerOff menu.)

If I store .zip with another modem firmware (a radio image from the list at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1158783) on /sdcard/, can I flash it from the recovery mode (so that the main system will be not touched otherwise and will work as before)?

(The .zip content looks like this:

```
$ unzip -l radio-cm-7-GalaxyS-JW4-signed.zip 
Archive:  radio-cm-7-GalaxyS-JW4-signed.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
   478916  05-31-11 15:37   busybox
    59848  05-31-11 15:37   erase_image
     1096  05-31-11 15:37   META-INF/CERT.RSA
      551  05-31-11 15:37   META-INF/CERT.SF
   224244  05-31-11 15:37   META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary
      594  05-31-11 15:37   META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
      498  05-31-11 15:37   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 12582912  03-16-12 04:47   modem.bin
      888  05-31-11 15:37   updater.sh
 --------                   -------
 13349547                   9 files
$
```

Although `modem.bin` files in two of the archives I've looked into don't differ in size, they do differ; and that's the only difference between the two archives.)

Comment: if your "modem firmware" is, as your tag selection suggests, a radio image, this should not touch anything but the radio firmware (which resides in a separate area). No guarantees, however -- as when the radio image is broken, you won't boot anywhere. So make sure you really have the correct one!

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I meant a firmware image from the list at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1158783

Comment: @Izzy Re "you won't boot anywhere" -- even into the recovery mode to flash another radio image?

Comment: What confuses me in that thread is the naming of `radio-cm-7-*` -- what has a radio to do with CM (CyanogenMod)? (but from the size, the archives cannot hold an entire CM7 ;) Also, those are a bit old, right? 2011?

Comment: "not anywhere", no. If the radio is broken, all that's left is a nice [brick](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29741/what-does-it-mean-to-brick-your-phone/29745#29745). Think of breaking the BIOS on your computer -- it also won't boot anything then.

Comment: Well, it did work.

Comment: Congrats! I no longer worry flashing some ROM, but with the radio image I'm always on alert (and glad when not needed or at least done :) -- So maybe you want to sum up an answer, and then accept it 2 days later?

Comment: @Izzy I'm thinking about writing a script that'd gather statistics for a list of different modem firmware, so that I can choose the best. It should run in the main system (say, CyanogenMod), get the next firmware from the list, save it, and reboot the device into recovery (modified CWM). The modified CWM, if it sees a radio firmware to test in a specified location, should flash it and reboot into CM. Then the script should be run automatically, test the connection quality with some test, save the result, and loop (to the beginning). There should be a break/confirmation button for intervention