# Bricked the phone by wiping every partition in TWRP

Tags: custom-roms, boot-loop, unbricking

My Redmi 5 plus won't boot as I messed up everything while trying to flash a couple of ROMs. At first the two ROMs that I flashed were working well. But after some time, whatever ROM I flashed, the phone started to restart while setting up the first boot (choosing language, region, etc.) and no further. So I tried wiping every partition there is under the TWRP wipe section (cache, system, vendor, data, internal storage, and so forth). Then flashed a custom ROM again with and without GApps but no success. I noticed that the phone even started to restart **before** the first boot finished. Also, after flashing stock ROM, TWRP said no OS installed. I even tried flashing stock MIUI ROM in fastboot mode. Although it went well, still bootloop and the device keeps restarting. However, before all of these problems, I did take a backup of every partition, leaving nothing behind, so I restored everything but again the `"No OS installed, are you sure to boot?"` message. Now I'm freaking out, not knowing what to do. I read somewhere that flashing via QPST tool may help but I'm having problems with installing it.

> If I manage to make my phone work again, I will not flash any other
>   ROM, ever.

Comment: Just a correction of terms: if you had really "bricked" your phone, it wouldn't boot at all (as a brick doesn't boot anything), see [What does it mean to “brick” your phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29741/16575) Apart from that: the "and so forth" details might give a clue. What else did you wipe? Cache and data is no issue. System isn't if you flash a fresh ROM afterwards. Not sure about vendor – but what else? Like, modem? Obviously not boot or recovery from what you describe.